# Draw horizontal lines between left floating divs in a various sized container

Tags: html, css-float

If I have more divs floating left in a container div, how can I draw lines between them horizontally if they don't fit in one row?

For example if:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="div1" style="float:left; width: 80px;"></div>
  <div id="div2" style="float:left; width: 80px;"></div>
  <div id="div3" style="float:left; width: 80px;"></div>
</div>
```

the main div's "**width**" becomes less than 240 px then the 3 contained div will be displayed in two rows. In this case I want to draw **full length lines between** these two rows.

Comment: do you mean with full length? the `240px` ?

Comment: I mean the full length is the length of the parent #main div ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the divs are of a known height, the best way is to have a repeating background image in the "main" id, like so:

```
#main {
background-image:url('horizontal_line.gif');
background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

The trick though is that horizontal_line.gif must have a height higher than that of the div units so that the line will be hidden if there's only one row.

horizontal_line.gif (or png) should be a straight line with a width of 1px and a height of, for example, 100px, where 99px are transparent and 1px at the bottom is the color of the line (assuming you want your line's thickness to be 1px)..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it with plain css and different height, you could do it this way (depending on you page structure you probably need to do some changes), it indeed adds some additional html code, but depending on what you want to do it is a fast end flexible solution.

because of the `overflow: hidden` it would not work in every situation.

**css**

```
#main {
    overflow: hidden; //<-- hides the line if the element is in the frist row
}

.line {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0px;
    top: -1px; //<-- hides the line if the element is in the frist row
    left: 0px;
    width: 240px; //<-- the full width of the line
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="div1" style="float:left; width: 80px;">
        <div class='line'></div>
        aaa<br>aaaaa
    </div>
    <div id="div2" style="float:left; width: 80px;">
        <div class='line'></div>
        aaa<br>aaaaa
    </div>
    <div id="div3" style="float:left; width: 80px;">
        <div class='line'></div>
        aaaa<br>aaaaa<br>aaaaaa
    </div>
</div>
```